# The n queen problem in Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

On page 34 of the 8th edition of *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications* by Rosen, he writes,

> Note that squares $(i, j)$ and $(i′, j′)$ are on the same diagonal if either $i + i′ = j + j′$ or $i − i′ = j − j′$.

However, I can't verify this. In particular, consider the square $(3, 4)$. According to Rosen, $(2, 1)$ should be on the diagonal of $(3, 4)$ as $3+2=4+1$. However, this is not the case.

According to me, $(i, j)$ and $(i', j')$ share a diagonal iff $|i-i'|=|j-j'|$.

Which is true? Is there an error in the book, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Maybe it is a typo... Maybe it is $i+j'=i'+j$

Comment: What Mauro wrote is equivalent to the second condition $i-i' =j-j' $

Comment: The book is wrong on one of the two conditions.  Two squares are on the same rising diagonal if $\color{red}{i+j=i'+j'}$, or on the same falling diagonal if $i-i'=j-j'$.